# akka http not handling parameters with dollar signs properly?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have (OData) query params defined in my route like so:

```
parameters(('$top.as[Int].?, '$skip.as[Int].?)) { (top, skip) =>
```

I have the following rejection handler to handle all invalid parameters (handleAll):

```
RejectionHandler.newBuilder()
  .handleAll[MalformedQueryParamRejection] { paramRejections =>
    // paramRejections is a Seq[MalformedQueryParamRejection]
    ...
  }
```

The problem is that when called with the following

```
some-endpoint?$top=invalid&$skip=invalid
```

The `paramRejections` in the rejection handler has 2 entries, **both** for $top, instead of one for $top and one for $skip.

Seems related to the dollar sign on the params, since when I remove this things work as expected. Is this a known issue or is there a workaround available (**that doesn't include removing the dollar sign**)?

Note, it seems its only the rejection handler that has a problem with multiple params starting with the dollar sign, since this line in the route correctly assigns top and skip to the variables when $top and $skip are supplied with valid values in the URI:

```
parameters(('$top.as[Int].?, '$skip.as[Int].?)) { (top, skip) =>
```

Comment: Does percent-encoding help with this issue? `%24top=` instead of `$top=`. Dollar sign is reserved as sub-delim and parsed properly only if percent encoded. It worked ok in my reproduction.

Comment: No, clients should be allowed to use dollar sign, as per OData standards: http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/

Comment: @chunjef thats irrelevant, all that matters is that the paramRejections supplied to handleAll is incorrect, as described in my question

Comment: Possible to get a minimum git repo for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with your route tree configuration, probably two candidate routes are evaluated and each one produce a `MalformedQueryParamRejection` for the `$top` query parameter.

> The paramRejections in the rejection handler has 2 entries, both for $top, instead of one for $top and one for $skip.

`handleAll` does not collect multiple `MalformedQueryParamRejection` originated from the same route, but it collects rejections from different routes.

`paramRejections` is a `Seq[MalformedQueryParamRejection]` but a single route could be rejected with just one `MalformedQueryParamRejection`, specifically (only) the first query parameter not matching the required format.

Try it with a minimal `route` configuration (as in the example below) and you'll experience the right behaviour:

```scala
val route = get {
  parameters(('$top.as[Int].?, '$skip.as[Int].?)) {
    (top, skip) => complete(s"$top, $skip")
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, there is an open issue to implement the behaviour I require; https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/1490